# Passing submit form to controller in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, post, submit

I have a submit form which I want to send to my RegisterController and I get this error
""Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"" 
The create method demands an array.How to convert my request ot an array?

the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('posting') }}">
                        @csrf....and so on
```

the routes:

```
Route::get('administration/register', function () {
    return view('vregister');
})->name('registration');


Route::post('/insert','Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('posting');
```

method of RegisterController.php

```
  protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user= User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);


        $role=Role::select('id')->where('name','Support')->first(); //??
        $user->roles()->attach($role);
        return $user;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong instance in your create method. When using forms, you should use `Request` class to actually send form data to your controller. The way you have it, no data is being sent to `create()` method, hence the error. Edit your `create()` method to this:

```
protected function create(Request $data)
```

And import Request class at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Read more at the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests)
.

EDIT:

To redirect to a specific page after saving the data, change your return statement to this:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

This will return you back to the previous page. You can also add any route here, that you wish to redirect to:

```
return redirect()->rote('route.name');
```

Comment: Thank you .It posts my data in phpmyadmin and I have the request on my page instead of home page.The redirect should be also in create method?

Comment: Didn't quite understand your question. You want to redirect to a specific page after user is successfully created?

Comment: yes,because after the  succes I get the array of request on my page.

Comment: It works.Zlatan thank you very much for your help.Sorry for not having enough reputation to give you "This answer is useful".